# How do you build and use the plcrashreporter in XCode 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, plcrashreporter

How do you build and use the http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/ PL Crash reporter tools for iOS in Xcode 3?

I downloaded the Google code project and it is the most complicated and confusing X-Code project I've ever seen.  What are the artifacts to build or copy out of the project to use in your own project to report code?

I built a simpler catch/email tool, but it doesn't give me the state of other threads.  Does anyone have a simple tutorial or explanation of how to use the more advanced features of the PLcrashreporter tool?

Answer (score 1):

The target used to build the disk image is 'Disk Image'; this will build the Mac OS X and iOS frameworks, documentation, and a standalone release disk image.

If you want to build the framework alone, the 'CrashReporter' target will build the iOS and Mac OS X frameworks, and the 'CrashReporter-iOS' target will build just the iOS framework.

You might need to hold down the option key and select 'Use Base SDK' when selecting the above build targets.